# In the United States, can I sue my ex significant other for turning me gay?

Tags: united-states, abuse

Suppose that a person A happily entered a mutually romantic heterosexual relationship with another adult B and after suffering through three years of daily abuse, deliberate cruelty and elaborate attempts by B to make A feel jealous A  separated themselves from B and swore off B's gender as a whole. Suppose that A is now an active homosexual and A and A's same gen partner C have decided to marry. Can A sue B for deliberate cruelty, abuse and emotional distress so severe that it turned A into a homosexual?

Answer (score 9):

For cruelty and abuse, yes.

For sexual orientation change, you would need to prove a loss, i.e. that you are damaged or diminished as a result of that change, and your current partner might find that rather offensive!  You would also need to prove your partner's culpability for that.

Those are very, very bold claims, which will require very, very bold proofs.  Realistically I think your prospects are very, very poor.  You have much better prospects on the ordinary abuse.

Further, the conversion claim will have terrible optics. It will gain national notoriety and will be the butt of jokes on late-night talk shows and "what is wrong with the world?" editorial columns.  *And I don't think I'm telling you anything you don't already know*.

It will generate a great deal of negative publicity for you, will reflect badly on LGBT (which is something you ought to think about since you're part of it)... and you will be *widely* viewed as  publicity-seeking opportunist and drama-maker, including by the judge and jury, and it will undercut your abuse claim.   For that reason, the opponent's legal team will do everything possible to amplify that.

The long-term effects will be that you'll be "Oh yeah, *that* person", and people won't take you seriously for decades to come.  It'll hurt your long term social and employment prospects.

It's the hard way to get your own page on Wikipedia.

Comment: I cannot in good conscience upvote this. While 90% of the answer is great, it appears to support the corporate propaganda re McDonald's coffee.

Comment: Fine, I'll remove it.  By the way @Studoku what happened when you actually read the McDonalds coffee ruling?

Comment: I re-evaluated my views on "lawsuit culture and the false narrative that injury lawsuits are poor people seeking easy money. Instead I realised that the vast majority involve people who actually suffered, some in third world nations without healthcare.

That's what just happened to you, right?

Comment: @Studoku Please elaborate, I'm lost!

Comment: @kisspuska There's a long-standing myth that injury lawsuits are people being greedy. A lot of people who believe that cite "I dun heard this lady burned her self cause she don't know coffee is hot". The actual case involves coffee being heated to a dangerous (well above boiling) temperature. The lady in question suffered third degree burns to her legs and genitals and permanent scarring, as well as significant medical bills.

Comment: @kisspuska Despite this, the corporate media push the myth that this was just someone trying to get rich quick to demonise people seeking lawsuits. You know, those workers getting injured/maimed/killed by unsafe conditions/asbestos/chemicals, that sort of thing.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_jaU5V9FUg explains it better than I can and it's from an actual lawyer in a suit.

Comment: @Studoku ah, ok, crystal clear! And what about the third world nations part, I don’t get that one

Comment: @kisspuska The nation it was in doesn't have healthcare.

Comment: This one slipped by me @studoku but your last May response made me realize we had been on the same page all along, on the McDonalds thing.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Looking back, I get the impression that you weren't supporting those editorials, just referencing that they exist. If so I apologise.

Comment: Some collateral gains too, great, thank you! Would you mind sharing the name of the case or a link?

Comment: @Studoku Thank you, but I also saw your side of it, as it was vulnerable to the misinterpretation you feared.  The answer is improved.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica And upvoted.

Comment: @kisspuska I can't really tell you more than the video. It's pretty infamous though so if you get past the editorialising you should be able to google it.

Comment: @Studoku I am watching it now. This is horrible, poor woman, and I neither find it frivolous, of course. (1) Don’t ask people if they want kid’s temperature when they told you they want their drink medium-hot (f* you *bucks!), (2) don’t ever give out drinks at unconsumable temperature, (3) go to jail if you fail to an extent that causes remaining bodily injury, (4) advise it’s hot (5) do reasonable precautions for any harm, pain and suffering to not occur and (6) do _extra_ precautions in a drive-through (my first thought was she’s locked in that cabin)

Comment: @studoku the non-economic nature of the damages are “special justifications” for the purposes of opening up the single-digit cap for punitive damages. The judge erred, per case law, in the reduction. And if you look at the singe-digit presumption, it’s a bad precedent. The function, other than enumerated in decisions of appeal and supreme courts, is handing out a fine. Normal, this is done by a consumer protection body of government. And it does not relieve the wrongdoer from lawsuits by individual plaintiffs. The one who successfully prosecuted a matter should receive equal punitive awards

Comment: As what would have been reasonable to be ordered payable by any such body. This would also provide for a watchdog society that is a hostile-enough environment for such systemic misconducts, fraud, negligence etc.

Answer (score 4):

If A is now happy with C and intending to marry, it would be hard to see how A's current same-gender preference is a wrong justifying money damages. Besides which it would be necessary to prove to the satisfaction of a judge or jury that B's actions has such an effect on A, which would be hard since I understand that current expert opinion does not support such a theory.

However, leaving aside the question of orientation  "daily abuse, deliberate cruelty and elaborate attempts by B to make A feel jealous"  might **possibly** constitute grounds for legal action. It would depend on the details of the "abuse". Physical assault, if proved, could be grounds for action. So can "Intentional Infliction of Emotional Distress". But there would need to be something far beyond an ordinary dysfunctional romantic relationship. As lot of this would be a matter of state law, so it would matter which state this was in. Unless the facts are rather extreme I do not see such an action being successful.

Anyone seriously considering such a legal action would do well to consult a competent lawyer.

Answer (score 2):

A can certainly sue B, but any argument about A's sexuality is best avoided.  The more persuasive evidence would be the specific factual details of the "daily abuse, deliberate cruelty and elaborate attempts by B to make A feel jealous."